# Display elementary math without evaluating

Tags: hold, display

Given a list of operators and integers, for instance

```
oper = {Subtract, Times, Plus}
{a, b, c, d} = {3, 5, 4, 9}
```

I would like to print

```
oper[[2]][oper[[1]] @@ {a, b}, oper[[3]] @@ {c, d}]
```

as $(3-5)\times (4+9)$ (set aside the $\LaTeX$ formatting, I just mean the numbers and the operators in a classical way). Whenever I use `Hold`, `Unevaluate` or `Inactivate`, the `oper[[2]]` and similar are not evaluated. Also the operator names are not replaced with their symbols.

Any hints?

Comment: For the purpose of displaying, consider strings.

Answer (score 6):

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d, oper]
oper = {Subtract, Inactive@Times, Inactive@Plus} /.
   Subtract -> (HoldForm[Plus[#, -#2]] &);
{a, b, c, d} = {3, 5, 4, 9};
oper[[2]][oper[[1]] @@ {a, b}, oper[[3]] @@ {c, d}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
(3 - 5)*(4 + 9) // Inactivate
```

$(3\ {\color{#b39980}+}{\text{ -}5})*(4\ {\color{#b39980}+}\ 9)$

If you only want to inactivate the heads that appear in `oper` while others occur:

```
hold = Function[e, Unevaluated[e] /. HoldPattern[oper[[a_]]] :>
                                      Inactive[Evaluate[oper[[a]]]], HoldAllComplete];

oper[[2]][oper[[1]] @@ {a, b}, oper[[3]] @@ {c, d}] // hold
```

${\color{#b39980}S\color{#b39980}u\color{#b39980}b\color{#b39980}t\color{#b39980}r\color{#b39980}a\color{#b39980}c\color{#b39980}t}[3,5]{\ \color{#b39980}*\ }(4{\ \color{#b39980}+\ }9)$

```
% /. Inactive[Subtract][a_, b_] :> (HoldForm[Plus[a, -b]])
```

$(3-5){\ \color{#b39980}*\ }(4{\ \color{#b39980}+\ }9)$